# can we write a own servlet in BIRT project?

Tags: tomcat, birt

I have a web application deployed on jboss now it calls a BIRT report deployed on tomcat (that is another web application) , how can i pass some session parameters to this BIRT application and process them any idea?

Please give your suggestions , thanks in advance.

Comment: what specific do you mean by session parameters? I used encrypted url parameters to send username & password  in some situations.

Comment: How do i fetch this parameters at this end (BIRT project) ?

Comment: for example use params["parameter_name"].value in script defined for specific event

Comment: did you mistitled this question? do you only need to pass some sort of authentication to the report?

Comment: yes.. i am very clr that i need this parameters just to authenticate the user while fetching the report , meaning if user is suman and has access to LINUX machine report data should not show Windows machine details , so i need this parameters there in order to validate the data security .

Comment: Given the clarifying comments this seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472724/protect-birts-report