# BIRT Security-constraint url-pattern issue with security policies in web.xml

Tags: xml, url, tomcat, authorization, birt

I'd like to restrict diferent users/groups to have access to view different reports.

For example those two reports should allow different users to view them:

x.x.x.x:x/birt-viewer/frameset?__report=report/zone1/report1.rptdesign

x.x.x.x:x/birt-viewer/frameset?__report=report/zone2/report2.rptdesign

**web.xml** fragment for one of the roles (I assume that I can have multiple security-constraints in this file, right?):

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
    ...
    <url-pattern>what2do</url-pattern>
    ...
<role-name>Zone1_Users</role-name>
```

I wonder how should I take care of that url-pattern parameter **to distinguish those URLs**? These don't work:

- `<url-pattern>/frameset?__report=report/zone1/*</url-pattern>`
- `<url-pattern>/frameset?__report=report/zone1/*.rptdesign</url-pattern>`
- `<url-pattern>/*/zone1/*</url-pattern>`
- `<url-pattern>/*/zone1/*.rptdesign</url-pattern>`

BIRT is on Tomcat on latest LTS Ubuntu.

As much as I found out I think that `<url-pattern>` ignores everything after `?` sign in URL. I may have to write second web-app on that Tomcat to resolve authorization. However, I don't know how to define security-roles in birt web.xml anyway.

Comment: Is the answer you need in existing question [Protect BIRT's report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472724/protect-birts-report)

Comment: I'm afraid no. I need to somehow distinguish my URL parametrs in <url-pattern>.