# How can i secure BIRT reports for users

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, birt

I deployed my spring application (with spring security and spring MVC) and BIRT viewer on tomcat on 1 port.
This application using basic authentication.

How can i run reports, using from this application (e.g. using hyperlinks or redirecting from my controller) so that will sending to BIRT username from session?

update:
I want to do redirect to birt [report](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Retrieve_Session_information_in_Script_(BIRT))

```
RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/birt/run?__report=application_session_integrationBF.rptdesign");
return new ModelAndView(redirectView);
```

How could i do this, with username? (not in url, i want to hide this)
Help me, please! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472724

Comment: It's a different questions, i want to send username to birt. And i know, how work with this username in report query.

Comment: to get username from session use this `<c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME}"/>` on the page, or `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();` on the controller. Now its up to you how to send this username to BIRT

Comment: The best way: instead of BIRT viewer, put it inside your own app. It will give you lots new possibilities of introducing new features in the future, and will make your problem disappear.